# OpenLayers.Filter.Logical not working

Tags: openlayers-2, filter

I have the following code:

```
   var map = {};
   var googleMercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
   var wgs84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
   var lyr_osm = {};
   var texas = {};
   var lll = {};
   var query = {};
   var fin = {};
   var fout = {};
function init(){
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";
//--------------------------------------------------map
    $(document).ready(function () {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
                    {
                    numZoomLevels: 18,
                    projection: googleMercator
                    }
       );
    });
//--------------------------------------------------layers definition
    var lyr_osm =new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM");
//--------------------------------------------------setting wms layer
       texas = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Texas",
           "http://54.228.242.237:80/geoserver/us_admin/wms",
           {
           'VERSION' : '1.1.0',
           layers: "us_states_gen",
           format: "image/png",
           transparent: true,
           cql_filter: "state_name LIKE 'Texas'",
           },
                {isBaseLayer: false,
                visibility: true,
                sphericalMercator: true,                        
                }
           );
//---------------------------------------------------filters
                             fin = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                                     type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.GREATER_THAN,
                                     property: "store_id",
                                     value: 500
                             });
                             fout = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                                     type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LESS_THAN,
                                     property: "store_id",
                                     value: 100
                             });
                             query = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
                                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
                                    filters: [fin, fout]
                             });

    var awfspc = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        url: 'http://loclahost/geoserver/stores/ows',
        featurePrefix: 'stores',
        featureType: 'stores',
            defaultFilter: fin,
            srsName: "EPSG:3857"        
    });

    lll = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points", {
             externalGraphic: 'http://localhost/black_marker32.png', 
             graphicHeight: 20, 
             graphicWidth: 20,
          strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
          protocol : awfspc,
    });

//--------------------------------------------------------------------map controls
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
//--------------------------------------------------------------------add Layers
    map.addLayers([lyr_osm, texas, lll]);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------map position
    var mapCenter = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-99, 31.3);
    mapCenter.transform(wgs84, googleMercator);
    map.setCenter(mapCenter,6);
//  map.zoomToExtent();
}
```

When I use fin filter or fout filter, the filters are applied and they return good. When I use querry filter, nothing is returned, no error and no data.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite logical that

```
store_id >= 500 AND store_id <= 100
```

doesn't return anything. Probably you mean

```
store_id >= 500 OR store_id <= 100
```

or

```
store_id <= 500 AND store_id >= 100
```